# how to connect google glass with web app

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have created a sample web app using mirror-api+php. How to connect that app with google glass. Any particular process to see that web content on google glass screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question further or discuss what you've done and what you're having problems with? As it stands right now, this is a pretty ambiguous question - you've already created an app using the Mirror API, so you're already "connected" to Glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi was missing one very important step, was login with non explorer account due to this I am unable to see the notifications on glass screen

Comment: Please help me on understanding Googleglass, My question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475749/how-to-pass-data-from-normal-android-app-to-google-glass-app-and-viceversa